# Подстановка строк в регулярках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая картинка:
[image: Регулярки]

И там есть такой блок как, "подстановка строк". Объясните, что это такое и как это использовать. Что-то у меня не особо получается, а примеров или объяснения по этому поводу я не могу найти.

Comment: Это для оператора замены, пишется во второй его части "на что заменить" и собственно подставляет в указанную позицию то, что указано в этой таблице. А вот что бы хоть какой то пример привести надо знать в каком языке у вас эти регулярки, что бы понимать как вообще выглядит такой "оператор".

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое. Использую Perl-совместимые регулярные выражения.

Comment: ну в синтаксисе перла в строке ABCD замена `s/A(.)(.)/$2-$&-$1-/` сделает из нее C-ABC-B-D потому как меняется весь найденный кусок целиком т.е. ABC на то что сказано в правой части. D просто остается на своем месте т.к. его "не находили"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подстановка строк- это шаблоны в строке замены, которые служат для замен в частей исходного текста с учетом совпадений в регулярном выражении.

Чтобы было понятнее: рассмотрим обычную функцию замены части строки, например [PHP:`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

```
$result = str_replace( "%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");
// <body text='black'>
```

Здесь произошла замена текста `%body%` текстом `black`, но в случае регулярных выражений мы имеем не только совпавший текст, но и части совпадения, которые несут в себе полезную нагрузку.

`$0` - все совпадение целиком
`$1` - первая группа, `$2` - вторая группа и т.д.

Теперь пример с [PHP:`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = "<HTML><BODY> http://google.com </BODY></HTML>";
$result = preg_replace( "/http:\/\/(\\S+)/", "<A href='$0'>$1</A>", $text );
// <HTML><BODY> <A href='http://google.com'>google.com</A> </BODY></HTML>
```

С регулярным выражением совпал текст `http://google.com` и он был заменен на шаблон `<A href='$0'>$1</A>` при этом в шаблоне содержаться совпавшие группы.

Остальные шаблоны замены из указанного в вопросе списка не поддерживается большинством реализаций регулярных выражений, полностью поддерживается в Perl и частично в JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

> Объясните, что это такое и как это использовать

Все просто. В регулярных выражениях все, что заключается в скобки `(` и `)` - является "захватывающей" группой, за исключением "незахватывающих" [просмотров](http://webmasterschool.ru/regex/ch9.php) вперед и назад. К этим группам можно ссылаться во второй части регэкспа, заменяющей. Реализаций замены в разных языках может быть множество.

Пример на языке Perl (заменяем первую цифру строки на цифру в кавычках):

```
$F = "   1234,hffffffff";
printf $F if ($F =~ s/(^\s*)(\d+)(.*$)/$1"$2"$3/s);
```

Вывод:

```
   "1234",hffffffff
```

В данном случае $1,$2,$3 - ссылаются на "захватываемые" группы.

Comment: Благодарствую. Очень информативно.